# Integrating ATAP (external Tool) into Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, automated-tests

I want to integrate Accelerating Test Automation Tool Platform (ATAP) Tool in my Eclipse. The tool basically helps to write English like Automation scripts. More info and related links for the tool is below:

1) https://github.com/s0nalP/ATAP

2) how it looks like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dO-KWYJ3zP0

I am not able to get it running into Eclipse for some reason. 
Here is what I tried :-

1) Go to Install New software option in Eclipse and giving there a git hub link. This did not work and says: ""No Software found at specified location".

2) doing git clone in Eclipse, creating local repository and then doing Import it into Eclipse with "Import" Option. This way I could have ATAP in my eclipse but with errors in org.Springframework.* imports. So I downloaded Spring from Eclipse Marketplace (in Eclipse for Java EE developers) but still errors do not go away !

It seems that the tool is Spring application and does not use Maven.  I just want to have running example of it in eclipse as it looks really interesting.
(I am afraid that the tool is complete on git hub to incorporate it into eclipse and use though! but just want to give it a try)

Could someone please point out:

1) what I am doing wrong ?

2) What is the best way to incorporate external Tool into Eclipse ? (if I have correctly integrated it into eclipse then In File -> New -> I should have an option ATAP Project. This is the goal)

Comment: Only Eclipse plug-ins can be integrated to the IDE. I took a look at the GitHub repository and it does not seem to define any plug-in, so the code may be proprietary. Plug-ins can be installed either from the Eclipse Marketplace or from an update site (which is kind of an archive accessible from an URL and that is provided by the developers) but I did not find any. Hence I guess that the plugin is not publicly available; you could try to contact the developers.

Comment: @echebbi Thank you for having look at it. Your comment clears my doubt.